# (Sublime text 2) Unable to run package setup:

Tags: sublimetext2

I am running Sublime text 2.0.2 Build 2221,
and I am getting this error on start up

```
Unable to run package setup:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 165, in
updgrade
upgradePackage(pkg, pristinedir,
datadir, backupdir)
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 158, in
upgradePackage
os.path.join(backupdir, base),
inhibitOverwite)
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 90, in
upgradeArchive
writeFile(fname, newar.read(f))
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 18, in
writeFile
with open(fname, 'wb') as fo:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file directory:
u'/Users/antonioortiz/Library/Application
Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/
ActionScript/ActionScript.tmLanguage'
```

I suspected it was the ActionScript/ActionScript.tmLanguage' so I trashed it but to no avail.
The only other info I can glean is I tried to link my files to dropbox so my work computer can take advantage of all the packages I find here and there and vice versa!
And it goes without saying I can't get past this prompt; i.e. I hit 'ok' and the app closes!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a little bit lost as to what you're trying to do. What is `PackageSetup.py` and where did you get it? What are you trying to upgrade or run? A few more details would definitely be helpful. Are you installing ST2 for the first time?

Comment: Well recently I tried to open Sublime text 2 and everything seemed to be off. So I reinstalled and am trying to reestablish my links to dropbox, but after I do that I get the error above.

Comment: What are your links to Dropbox? Do you just have a symlink to `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`, or is it something different?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try. First, move whatever your Dropbox directory is to a backup folder. For example, if you've linked `Dropbox/Sublime/Packages` to `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`, then move it to `Dropbox/Backup/Packages`. You can then create a new, empty `Dropbox/Sublime Text 2/Packages` directory. Next, delete both `/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app` and all the contents of `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2`. Then, in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2`, run the following from the command line:

```
ln -s /path/to/Dropbox/Sublime/Packages ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages
```

to create a new symlink to an empty Dropbox Packages directory. Finally, rerun the Sublime setup (I think it just involves copying `Sublime Text 2.app` from the `.dmg` file to `/Applications`), then run `/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app` and see if everything works.

If it does, fantastic. If it doesn't, please post the full text of any error messages, and you may need to fiddle with Dropbox's settings. I've seen [several other reports](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sublime+text+dropbox) of Dropbox not always playing nice with Sublime, although the versions, details, and operating systems vary. I'm just about to try it myself, so I can learn about what the issues are.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I tried to fix this problem, since it worked for me, so I tended to shared it. I use *Macbook Air* though.

I just go down to the directory `~/Library/ApplicationSupport/Sublime Text 2/Packages/ActionScript/ActionScript.tmLanguage` and use `vim` to create an empty file named `ActionScript.tmLanguage` and then restarted sublime text 2, finally it got started.

*Hope it may help.*